# R modify default function behavior sys.date()

Tags: r

I always use the function [sys.date()](https://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-devel/library/base/html/Sys.time.html). However, I don't like the default date format, which is

> %Y-%m-%d
>
> 2018-07-23

What I want is to get the date with this format :

> %d-%m-%Y
>
> 23-07-2018

Now I know that I can specify the format desired like this :

> today <- Sys.Date()
>
> format(today, format="%d-%m-%Y")

**BUT**, what I want is to change the behavior of the function sys.date(), so that instead of returning a date with the format %Y-%m-%d, it returns the date with the format %d-%m-%Y, **by default.**

Is it possible to do such thing ?

Comment: You can overwrite the `Sys.Date` function to return whatever you want e.g. `Sys.Date <- function(x) paste0(base::Sys.Date(), 'nonsense')`, but overwriting base functions is considered bad practice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Build your own custom function around `Sys.Date()`:

```
custom_date <- function() {
    today <- Sys.Date()
    return(format(today, format = "%d-%m-%Y"))
}

custom_date()
```

Comment: The problem is that I'm using sys.date() everywhere and if I create another function, I'm gonna have to check every occurence of sys.date() and replace them when needed.

Comment: I think that's your only option, just replace everywhere `Sys.Date()` with `custom_date()`

Comment: Well if that's my only option I will do that, thanks !

Comment: Don't do this. Return a `Date` but add another S3 class and then define a `print` and a `format` method.